# Converting Table to interdependency/dependency matrix

Tags: r, excel, statistics

Hi There I hope you are doing good :)

My raw data format looks like the description below. abc are companies t1 t2 are technologies

```
   //T1 T2 T3 T4
   a 1 1 0 1
   b 1 0 1 0
   c 1 1 0 1
   d 0 1 1 1
```

I would like to have an interdependency Matrix that looks like that:

```
// T1 T2 T3 T4
T1 0  2. 1. 2
T2 2. 0. 1. 3
T3 1  1  0  1
T4 2  3  1. 0
```

Basically, I want to count how many same technology pairs (T1-T2 or T1-T4) are offered by how many companies, which represents the value in the matrix.

Example: 3 Companies (a,c,d) offer both the technology t2 AND t4

Can you please show me how to do that either in excel or in R :)

Answer (score 1):

```r
data <-
  structure(
    list(
      T1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L),
      T2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L),
      T3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L),
      T4 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-4L)
  )

m <- as.matrix(data)
res <- crossprod(m, m)
diag(res) <- 0
res
#>    T1 T2 T3 T4
#> T1  0  2  1  2
#> T2  2  0  1  3
#> T3  1  1  0  1
#> T4  2  3  1  0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this in R -

```
count_1s <- function(x, y) sum(df[[x]] == 1 & df[[y]] == 1)
n <- 1:nrow(df)
res <- outer(n, n, Vectorize(count_1s))
diag(res) <- 0
dimnames(res) <- list(colnames(df), colnames(df))
res

#   T1 T2 T3 T4
#T1  0  2  1  2
#T2  2  0  1  3
#T3  1  1  0  1
#T4  2  3  1  0
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(T1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), T2 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), 
    T3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), T4 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, this formula copied down and across:

```
=(COUNTIFS(INDEX($B$2:$E$5,0,COLUMN(A1)),1,INDEX($B$2:$E$5,0,ROW(A1)),1)*(ROW(A1)<>COLUMN(A1)))
```

[image]